# Record total time transpired from timer in lua

Tags: timer, lua

I'm quite new to lua, and I'm trying to make a function for a video game, where once the player joins the game, it starts a timer, and when he leaves, the timer stops.

And I want to to find the total time transpired, I'm aware of timers in lua, but I'm not sure how I would go about finding the total time transpired.

I would provide some sample code if I would, but I honestly have no direction on this issue.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_(programming_language)): "Lua (/ˈluːə/ loo-ə, from Portuguese: lua [ˈlu.(w)ɐ] meaning moon; **explicitly not "LUA"**" (emphasis mine)

Comment: Which engine are you developing the game in?

Comment: @hjpotter92 It's for Garry's Mod, Source Engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`os.time()`](http://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html) to get the seconds since epoch--once at the start and once at the end of whatever you're trying to measure.  Subtract, and you've got the elapsed seconds (wall time).